# How to add custom routes in ASP.NET Core MVC for Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm used to work with ASP.NET MVC framework but now I've moved on to ASP.NET Core MVC, and routes seem to be something else.

This is the project structure (Identity is scaffolded)

[image]

This is how I can add a custom route like in classic ASP.NET MVC:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "About",
       url: "About",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
    );
```

In this example I'm using `https://localhost/About` instead of `https://localhost/Home/About`

I'm trying to achieve the same thing using ASP.NET Core MVC, but I can't find any article related to this and the "url" attribute does not exist anymore.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Charts}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Register",
                pattern: "{controller=Identity/Account}/{action=Register}");                
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

I would like to add a custom route to `https://localhost/Identity/Account/Register` to `https://localhost/Register`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ERP_MKM.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using ERP_MKM.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using ERP_MKM.Services;

namespace ERP_MKM
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI();
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>(i =>
                new EmailSender(
                    Configuration["EmailSender:Host"],
                    Configuration.GetValue<int>("EmailSender:Port"),
                    Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EmailSender:EnableSSL"),
                    Configuration["EmailSender:UserName"],
                    Configuration["EmialSender:Password"]
                )
            );  
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            );
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Charts}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "Register", 
                     pattern: "Register", 
                     defaults: new { area = "Identity", controller = "Account", action = "Register" });             
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try: 
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Register",
     pattern: "Register",
     defaults: new { area = "Identity", controller = "Account", action = "Register" });

Comment: It doesn't work, keeps showing blank view

Comment: As an alternative, you can use app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); }); on Startup.cs and on the method "Register" inside the AccountController use the route attribute [Route("Register")]. But on the other controllers you must set the route attribute such as [Route("[controller]")].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers mapping

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "any-route-name",
    pattern: "register",
    defaults: new { area = "Identity", controller = "Account", action = "Register" }
);
```

For Razor pages there are `AddPageRoute` and `AddAreaPageRoute` methods. This code should be inside `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Register", "/Register");
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "/Login");
});
```

And don't forget to have line of code to enable pages in endpoints

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapRazorPages(); // this one
});
```

You can scaffold page to include and modify it in your project using Visual Studio.
[image]
[image]

Select required pages, select user context and click OK. This screenshot is also useful to find out all paths to pages in Identity area.

[image]

Comment: updated it with startup.cs file appended to main post

Comment: startup.cs won't help. show directory structure of your project

Comment: added structure as an image, something that may be worth to say is that identity is scaffolded and it's not present in the Controllers folder